# Query event durations

Tags: mysql, t-sql

Assume I have a notes table which contains (amongst other things) an entry which indicates when an employee starts/ends work on a project; there will only be one note that indicates the "start", but there could a number of different entries to indicate the "end" (we would ignore any extra "end" dates"). There will be times that have multiple people working on the project, as well as times when no-one is working on the project.

I need to query the table, to establish the number of days where the project had someone working on it:

```
projectID    dateStart     dateEnd
---------    ----------    ----------
20769720     2018-01-26 
20769720                   2018-01-29
20769720                   2018-02-02
20769720                   2018-03-20
20825496     2018-02-07 
20825496     2018-02-12
20825496                   2018-03-07
20825496     2018-03-15
```

The above table is what we have extracted as 'key' events depicting the start/end dates and can see that:

[Project 20769720] has someone working on 26-29th January (4 days);
[Project 20825496] has someone working from 7th Feb to 7th March (28 days) and from 15th March to present (19 days) = total 47 days

We considered hogging out the data to a temporary table and processing the data with a number of updates, but we can't create a temporary tables, cursors or stored procedures for this; it all has to be in a query, to return:

```
projectID    days
---------    ----
20769720     4
20825496     47
```

Comment: What's with the end dates for 20769720 on 1/29 and 3/20? Are those extra end dates with no start dates?

Comment: @Tingo there are multiple reasons that work on a project will end; we use the first of the 'end' dates and ignore any subsequent dates, when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

Get the min dateStart and max dateEnd, and find the difference. Keep in mind that is a project starts and stops (ie. has gaps in work), this will not work properly.

```
SELECT
    projectID,
    DATEDIFF(min(dateStart),max(dateEnd)) as `days`
FROM projectLog a
GROUP BY projectID
```

Comment: Exactly; there will be gaps in the dates, so we cannot use a simple min/max calculation.